# How to load images linearly or non-linearly in Objective-C / iOS?

Tags: ios, nonlinear-functions

I want to create an iOS app that utilizes full-screen photographs, which may turn into a lot of wait time for the end user if they are on a slow connection. Instead of showing them a "loading" icon, I want to display the image as it loads either linearly (from top to bottom the way a web browser might load images) or more interestingly, in a non-linear fashion. By that I mean, is there a function/method that would load pixels/sections randomly from any part of the image until the image is fully complete?

Answer (score 2):

You should look at

```
CGImageSourceCreateIncremental and CGImageSourceUpdateData
```

methods here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGImageSource/Reference/reference.html

You can also try NYXImagesKit library (https://github.com/Nyx0uf/NYXImagesKit)

Algorithm description - http://cocoaintheshell.com/2011/05/progressive-images-download-imageio/

Sample:

```
NYXProgressiveImageView * imgv = [[NYXProgressiveImageView alloc] init];
imgv.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
[imgv loadImageAtURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yourimage"]];
[self.view addSubview:imgv];
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like this is the progressive version. Do you know of any function that would instead load random pixels/areas until the image is fully loaded?

Comment: No. It should be rather difficult - I do not think there is a Cocoa class that supports random (non-progressive) image displaying. Anyway you can try to find a third-party library for that.

Comment: Also you can use images with interlace - probably it will a little improve loading/displaying process.